# Gerar numero sequencial dentro de um mês

Tags: php

Como gerar números sequencial constituídos por ano, mês, sequência de 5 dígitos.
sendo que os dígitos zerem ao mudar o mês?

Exemplo:

```
14 // ANO
11 // MÊS
00000 // SEQUÊNCIA QUE AO MUDAR O MÊS ZERA
```

Ficando: `141100000`..`141100001`..`141100002`

Ao mudar o mês: `141200000`..`141200001`..`141200002`

Esses números são atribuídos a uma ordem de serviço e salvo no DB, obviamente que serão únicos.

Minha função está assim:

```
function generateNumber(){
     return date('ym').'00000'; //141100000
}
```

Comment: você irá atribuir esse número ao inserir uma nova ordem no DB, correto?

Comment: correto @BrunoCalza

Comment: q DB você está usando? talvez fiquei mais fácil fazer em sql

Comment: é mySQLi ... :)

Comment: Esse campo é um varchar ou int? nessa tabela de ordem de serviço existe um campo `data_de_entrada` ou `data_de_registro` ?

Comment: Oi @perdeu, a coluna **os_numero** que se refere a questão acima, é do tipo VARCHAR, tbm tem uma coluna **os_data** do tipo TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode extrair o número da última ordem de serviço e gerar uma nova, fazendo uma consulta que retorne o maior número daquele mês e adicionar mais um, caso a consulta não retorne nada significa que é a primeira OS, como isso não muda pode fixar o código em outra função.

```
<?php
function conectarBanco(){
    return new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'base');
}

function primeiraOrdemMes(){
    return date('ym'). '00001';
}

function novaOrdemServico(){
    $db = conectarBanco();
    $sql = 'SELECT max(numero_ordem_servico) as ultimo_id FROM ordem
            WHERE month(data_entrada) = month(now()) ';

    $result = $db->query($sql);

    //já existe uma ordem cadastrada no mês
    if($result === true){
        $ordem_servico = $result->fetch_assoc();
        return ++$ordem_servico['ultimo_id'];
    }else{
        return primeiraOrdemMes();
    }
}

$nova_ordem = novaOrdemServico();
```

Comment: hoje você ganhou! obg man.

Answer (score 3):

Uma solucao possivel para o seu problema seria criar uma sequencia no banco de dados e reseta-la com um scheduler do proprio banco de dados no inicio de cada mes.

Dessa forma seu codigo ficaria assim:

```
function generateNumber(){
    // obtem o numero da sequencia do banco de dados
    $proximoNumeroSequencia = $banco->proximoNumeroSequencia('nome_sequencia');

    return date('ym') . $proximoNumeroSequencia; //141100000
}
```

Em bancos como o Oracle e o PostgreSQL é facil fazer isso usando o comando `CREATE SEQUENCE` do banco de dados para criar a sequencia, o comando `nextval` para obter o proximo valor da sequencia e usar o scheduler nativo para resetar a sequencia no inicio de cada mes.

Comment: legal @RenatoDinhaniConceição, a parte do reset no mysqli é que preciso ver

Comment: MySQL**i** nada mais é do que um meio de acesso ao SGBD. Quem tem de suportar o recurso é o MySQL. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Escrevi um algoritmo que gera o incremento do id caso já exista um caso no banco para o mês e ano atual – senão ele gera o primeiro id.

```
public function geraId()
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "login", "senha", "db");
    $result = $mysqli->query("
        SELECT id
        FROM tabela
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 1", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT));
    if (sizeof($result) == 1) {
        $lastId = $result[0]["id"];
        $lastIdYear = substr($lastId, 0, 2);
        $lastIdMonth = substr($lastId, 2, 2);
        if ($lastIdYear == date('Y') && $lastIdMonth == date('m')) {
            $id = substr($lastId, 4, 5);
            $id++;

            return $id;
        }
    }
    $id = date('Y-m') . '00001';

    return $id;
}
```

Comment: como vai @RodrigoRigotti, cara o final de 5 dig. ta sequencial na sua rotina?

Comment: @Hugo a sequência se forma quando eu incremento o último Id encontrado no banco para aquele mês e ano. Depois é só aproveitar esse id em sua próxima inserção.